# Nifi: append an flowfile attribute to the flowfile content (at the end)

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using putdatabaserecord to store a value into DB.

I also have a flow based on failure link to (this processor), so that failed record will be stored in disc for troubleshooting.

I can store the failed record in disc by using putfile processor.

Now i wanted it to be more informative during debugging. As the attribute "putdatabaserecord.error" contains the error reason, i want to append the flowfile content with this error reason as well.

I tried to achieve this using below flow. (attached visualization)

putsql/putdbrecord -> failure-> updateattribute (this is to give the flowfile a realistic name)-> attributesToJson (destination flowfileattribute/content -> putfile

but in attributesTOJson , if the destination is kept as flowfileattribute, the flowfile don't get this attribute and if destination is kept as flowfile content, original flowfile content is overrided.

My requirement is to append this single attribute to the existing flowfile content and not to override it.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Is existing flowfile content record-based?

Comment: existing flow file is just a error record in the form of json - [{"id":280,"index_id":1,"state_id":1}]

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ScriptedTransformRecord` [processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.21.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ScriptedTransformRecord/index.html):

- `Record Reader`: `JsonTreeReader`
- `Record Writer`: `JsonRecordSetWriter`
- `Script Language`: `Groovy`
- `Script Body`:

```java
record.setValue("error_msg", attributes["putdatabaserecord.error"])
record
```

Input (JSON):

```json
[
  { 
    "id": 280,
    "index_id": 1,
    "state_id":1
  }
]
```

Output (JSON):

```json
[
  { 
    "id": 280,
    "index_id": 1,
    "state_id": 1,
    "error_msg": "value from attribute"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @tonykoval  I learnt a new way with your above solution. I want to let know here, that i used jolttransform json processor to achieve the same. and it also worked.